# tailwind auto scrollable table in grid element, is possible?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Can add scroll only on tbody? I try write in tailwind scrollable table, I use grid. I add on the whole element, it doesn't look good.

The example shows a table in a grid 3x3, the table has 2 rows and 2 columns

My Code

```
  <div class="h-screen w-full grid gap-2 p-2" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);">
    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-2 rounded-xl bg-white overflow-auto">
      <table class="table-auto w-full">
        <thead class="sticky top-0 bg-gray-700 text-white">...</thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-xl bg-white">02</div>
  </div>
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/z6seLjgq/12/

[image]